# I will like to know how to pull out the duplicate information

Tags: csv, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So I am new to pandas python. Currently, I am tasked to identify which IDs in the "id" column are duplicate. For example, if ID 413 appears more than 1 time, it is considered duplicate. Since there are more than 600,000 IDs, i need to know the code to it. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas.Series.duplicated) which will return a boolean series to mask the df and then call [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas.Series.unique) to return an array of the duplicated IDs:

```
In [196]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[0,1,1,3,4,5,6,6,6,]})
df
Out[196]:
   ID
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   6
8   6
In [201]:

df[df['ID'].duplicated()]['ID'].unique()
Out[201]:
array([1, 6], dtype=int64)
```